# Vertically center element and switch to align top if height is too small

Tags: css, overflow, center, vertical-alignment

I have been trying to find an answer to this, but all I have found are only discussing centering an element vertically.

What I am trying to do is center a div vertically, which I know how to do with css. The problem is if the height is too small it will still center it and cut off top and bottom.

Here is a demo of what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/reitermarkus/23B43/
Fullscreen demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/reitermarkus/23B43/show/light/

Can you tell me how to align it to top if the height is too small? Preferably without JS.

Thank you,
Markus

Comment: The only way you could possibly determine whether the height is below the minimum required is through JS.

Comment: I found out that it works with CSS media queries using max-height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you could possibly determine whether the height is below the minimum required is through JS:

```
    var el = document.getElementById('id');   
    var el_height = el.offsetHeight;

    if(el_height < min_height){
    //apply class or inline style
    el.className = 'align_top';
    }
```

Obviously you'll need to define the min_height var. Furthermore for DOM manipulation it would be better to use jQuery. Aligning the element to the top of the document would just be a case of removing the negative margin and defining 'top' as 0;

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, but in fact there is a way to do it without JS.   
I didn't know you could use media queries with max-height, but it works perfectly.

Comment: Ah, sorry I thought you meant the height of the div not the browser viewport. Additionally it's worth mentioning that media queries are only supported in modern browsers, you would still have to use JS for backward compatability.